# WPF Button not disabling instantly

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a login page and I want the login button to disable while the SQL query is checking whether it's a valid account.

This is so that you can't press the login button twice or more times while it's already trying to do it's thing. Just like any decent software.

When I call 
`signinButton.IsEnabled = false`
in my signinButton_Click method it doesn't disable it until after my SQL has returned...

If I call MessageBox.Show("called") it will display it instantly, as expected, but for some reason that's not the same with IsEnabled.

Do I really need to use a seperate thread for this? It seems overly complicated, all I want to do is disable the button instantly, and not after the SQL has finished.

Much appreciated

Comment: how do you make a call to DB? is it async or synchronous? You should put some code in order for people to understand your problem ,  not having to guess what you may have written

Comment: "Do I really need to use a seperate thread for this?" Yes.  Implementation may vary based on personal preference and Visual Studio version, but ultimately it's as simple as that -- Yes.

Comment: you mean the .net framework version?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using async versions of your database calls with the `await` keyword. This allows your UI to be updated while query results are loaded.